# help with permanent Redirect in .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I'm using plogger with wordpress and I'm in the process of moving current photos to new directories.  I need to setup a permanent redirect once I change the directory

For example.

Current location: `www.mysite.com/products/cakes/birthday/batman-cake.html`

New location:     `www.mysite.com/products/cakes/superhero/batman-cake.html`

So if someone types in the current location it should redirect to the new location.

I have 2 .htaccess files.  One in the root directory and one in the Plogger directory.  the plogger one I assume is used to make the urls pretty and I think this is where I need to make the changes.  Also I only want to redirect individual pages and not the entire directory

See the plogger .htaccess below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /products
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/products/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=2]
  RewriteRule feed/$ plog-rss.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Please note that someone set this up for me a while ago and I'm not a programmer but I'm a little technical.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^products/cakes/birthday/batman-cake.html$ /products/cakes/superhero/batman-cake.html [R=301,L]

  RewriteBase /products
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.|/$)
  RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/products/$1 [R=301,L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [S=2]
  RewriteRule feed/$ plog-rss.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
  RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I tried this but I always get a 404 page not found.  There must be something missing here.  The closest I can get to making this work for me is modifying the .htaccess file under the root directory as follows:                                                     Redirect 301 /products/cakes/birthday/batman-cake.html http://products/cakes/superhero/batman-cake.html?       The problem here is that I must put the trailing "?" question mark and this Always shows up in the URL.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: missed the trailing $

Comment: Still no luck, just getting the 404 page.  Any way to debug what is happening behind the scenes on my godaddy account?